# Passing List<int> as an input parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I already have working examples like the following, to essentially get results from a SQL query from C#:

```
  Order GetOrder(int orderId)
  {
    List<OracleParameter> parameters = new()
    {
        new("Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2, orderId, ParameterDirection.Input)
    };
    OracleDataReader reader = await GetDataReaderAsync(connection, "my_package.GetOrder", parameters);
    ... //read the results
```

======

```
PROCEDURE GetOrder(Id in number,results out sys_refcursor) IS
BEGIN 
Open results for
Select 
buyer, orderDate, cost
from Order 
WHERE Id = Id
END GetOrder;
```

But I am stuck trying to make a version `GetOrders(List<int> orderIds)`. I have already come across [OracleParameter.CollectionType](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleParameterClass.htm#BABJEFCI) and I have read several questions:

- [Passing array to Oracle procedure from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279185/passing-array-to-oracle-procedure-from-c-sharp)
- [Passing an array of data as an input parameter to an Oracle procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885575/passing-an-array-of-data-as-an-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-procedure)
- [Retrieve the vales of PLSQLAssociativeArray In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010911/retrieve-the-vales-of-plsqlassociativearray-in-c-sharp)

Each addresses a different piece but I cannot anywhere find an end-to-end example. I'm not an Oracle guy though - though I can write queries, creating a procedure I rely on finding an example and copying it with modifications. This stuff about associative arrays and defining custom PLSQL types is just confusing me, especially if I have to create a type for each procedure... I only understand simple scalar DB types not passing tables as parameters.

Could anyone show me (or point me to the duplicate answer I can't find) a rough outline of how I'd create a GetOrder**s** version of the above - the changes made in C# & PL/SQL to handle the List parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a table-valued parameter from C# to Oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712355/how-to-pass-a-table-valued-parameter-from-c-sharp-to-oracle-stored-procedure)

Comment: @PeterCsala no... I can barely understand that question but it is about custom types and table mapping, not passing simple array/list data. My question is a basic "how do I do X" and theirs seems to be a more specific question about one aspect of this once you understand the basics of X

Comment: MSSQL does support a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) which allows you to define a table type with a single column and pass it to a stored procedure. So, you can map your `List<int>` to this custom table type. According to the above SO topic it seems like that same is achievable via UDT in Oracle.

Comment: @PeterCsala yes, the topics I link to myself refer to this sort of thing (the PLSQLAssociativeArray thing, I think) - I just can't piece the various bits together.